# how to add checked event to checkbox in databound datagrid in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, events, gridview

I have datagridview with multiple columns in my asp.net website. And I am displaying a backend sql stored procedure output into this grid using page OnLoad event. First column in the grid contains a checkbox. I have added this checkbox through ItemTemplate, so that all rows will have a checkbox for selecting the row. I want user able to select the checkbox and based on this selection I would like to perform a DB operation.

currently i am using like below, but couldn't able to trigger the event.

```
<asp:GridView ID="resultGridView" runat="server" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Processed">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxProcess" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="resultgrid_CellContentClick" 
                            Checked="false" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

on my code behind, I have method resultgrid_CellContentClick() for checkbox selection change event. But this code, never executed when select checkbox on/off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set `AutoPostBack="true"` in your checkbox, that's why your checkbox event handler did not work. Just set it...

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxProcess" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" 
 OnCheckedChanged="resultgrid_CellContentClick" Checked="false" />
```

Comment: if i use AutoPostBack="true", my pageload is firing again and my grid is reloading with no checkbox selection. How do i isolate this?

Comment: Your page load code should be like... if(!IsPostBack) {Populate Gridview code......}